# What will happen if I reference the instruction which is unloaded by dlclose?

Tags: posix

Suppose I've two threads: A, B. Thread A is running some instructions which locates in a loaded shared library at the same time, thread B `dlclose()` the shared library.
What will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same process, two threads sharing the same *handle* following a call to *dlopen()*, if one thread closes the opened library with *dlclose(handle)*, the other thread (actually, any of the two) using the *handle* causes an undefined behavior (usually, *Segmentation fault*).

More specifically, from the [dlclose man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlclose)

> dlclose()
>
> The function dlclose() decrements the reference count on the dynamic library handle handle.  If the reference  count  drops  to  zero  and no other loaded libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library is unloaded.